# Android Kotlin: "findViewById<Typ>" vs. "findViewById() as Typ"

Tags: android, kotlin, generics

Is there a difference?

```
val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.submitButton)
val button1 = findViewById(R.id.submitButton) as Button
```

If I do ...

```
Log.i("button", button::class.java.toString())
Log.i("button1", button1::class.java.toString())
```

... then I receive the result:

```
... button: class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
... button1: class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
```

**Is one of the two ways preferable over the other and why?**

Comment: If you say `val button: Button = findViewById()` that's the best option

Comment: I'd prefer the first way (explicitly passing generic), or `val button: Button = findViewById()` implicit passing of generic by type declaration. Type casting isn't the best option tbh.